# Unit Test for CreateDatabaseConnection method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, methodology

Using: Microsoft Unit Testing Framework integrated with VS2010

I have a class that implements this interface.

```
public interface IConnectionManager
{
    IDbConnection OpenDatabase(string path);
    void CloseDatabase();
}
```

I would like to create a set of Tests for these methods but not quite sure how to proceed.

What is the best way to test this?

Thanks.

### EDIT:

My `OpenDatabase` implementation looks something like this:

```
    public OleDbConnection OpenDatabase (string p_path)
    {
        if (Library.StringOperations.IsNullOrEmpty (p_path))
            return null;

        bool error = false;
        string  connectionString= @"CONNECTION STRING HERE";
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con= new OleDbConnection (connectionString);
            con.Open ();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            error = true;
        }

        if (!error)
            return con;

        return null;
    }
```

As suggested by @rdkleine I want to test the returned connection.

A few questions:

1. Do I need to create a new OleDbConnection object to compare with my returned object or should I check my returned connection object proprieties?
2. Can Mock Objects be used in this case?
3. Having in mind that I am testing a connection to a DB is this still *Unit Testing* or *Integration Testing*?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start simple.

- Test returns connection
- Test path exists
- Test path doesn't exist
- Test can't connect
- Test can connect

etc

[Read this book about TDD :)](http://artofunittesting.com/)